# What is the public endpoint for BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery, looker

To allow JDBC connections out of a secured network to BigQuery via Looker I need to know the domain name for BigQuery so that we can whitelist it in our proxy access list.

We are planning to set our proxy as the `rootURL` JDBC parameter. But the question is: which API endpoint does BigQuery provide for an on-premise Looker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

service endpoint `https://bigquery.googleapis.com`

[Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest#service-endpoint)